# How can I avoid this Error using Keras Lambda Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras(Tensorflow) in python to build a model for training dataset. And my input layer is a tensor with shape of (?, 4, 3010, 1) and I want to split it to two independent tensors(layers) both with shape of (?, 4, 1005, 1) and continue building the model.

So I build the model as below:

```
def build(window_size):
    model_input = Input(shape=(4, window_size*2, 1))
    inp_1, inp_2 = Lambda(tf.split, arguments={'axis': 2, 'num_or_size_splits': 2})(model_input)
   
    c1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_1)
    c2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_2)
    ......
```

And I run the code below:

```
model = build(1501)
```

Then I get the ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-be3139d89e09> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 model = build(1501)
      3 plot_model(model_before_reconstructed, show_shapes=True)
      4 


<ipython-input-27-cb9ad78acbd0> in build_1(window_size, inp)
      8     c1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_1)
----> 9     c2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_2)

/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/NG/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    581 
    582             # Handle mask propagation.
--> 583             previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
    584             user_kwargs = copy.copy(kwargs)
    585             if not _is_all_none(previous_mask):

/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/NG/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in _collect_previous_mask(input_tensors)
   2750             inbound_layer, node_index, tensor_index = x._keras_history
   2751             node = inbound_layer.inbound_nodes[node_index]
-> 2752             mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
   2753             masks.append(mask)
   2754         else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Strange thing is *inp1* and *inp2* has the same shape(I tried to print and figure out this) but only *inp1* can be sent into Conv2D layer and *inp2* raise the ERROR.

Then I also try this and it can run normally.

```
def build(window_size):
    model_input = Input(shape=(4, window_size*2, 1))
    inp_1, inp_2 = Lambda(tf.split, arguments={'axis': 2, 'num_or_size_splits': 2})(model_input)
    c1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_1)
    c2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(4, 8), padding='valid', input_shape=[4, window_size, 1])(inp_1)
    ......
```

Why this ERROR raised and how can I solve it if I can? Thank you very much.

BTW, my Python environment

```
# packages in environment at /Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/NG:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.0            py35hd172556_0    defaults
biopython                 1.72                     pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            hecd8cb5_1    defaults
certifi                   2020.6.20          pyhd3eb1b0_3    defaults
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.18              h18a8e69_0    defaults
decorator                 4.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
expat                     2.3.0                h23ab428_2    defaults
freetype                  2.5.5                         2    defaults
gettext                   0.19.8.1             hb0f4f8b_2    defaults
glib                      2.68.0               hdf23fa2_0    defaults
graphviz                  2.38.0                        4    defaults
h5py                      2.8.0            py35h878fce3_3    defaults
hdf5                      1.10.2               hfa1e0ec_1    defaults
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3    defaults
imageio                   2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233    defaults
ipykernel                 4.9.0                    py35_1    defaults
ipython                   6.0.0                    py35_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py35_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
joblib                    0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2    defaults
jsonschema                2.6.0            py35h2dd9e4b_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_7    defaults
jupyter_client            5.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0    defaults
keras                     2.0.6                    py35_0    conda-forge
keras-vis                 0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1    defaults
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h1de35cc_1    defaults
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2    defaults
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2    defaults
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0    defaults
libprotobuf               3.6.0                hd9629dc_0    defaults
libtiff                   4.0.6                         5    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.0                      py35_0    defaults
matplotlib                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.7.4                    py35_0    defaults
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1    defaults
mock                      2.0.0            py35hb42c812_0    defaults
nbconvert                 4.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1    defaults
networkx                  2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  5.0.0                    py35_0    defaults
numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.0.2u               h1de35cc_0    defaults
pandas                    0.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pbr                       5.5.1                      py_0    defaults
pcre                      8.44                 hb1e8313_0    defaults
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003    defaults
pillow                    7.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1    defaults
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py35_0    defaults
protobuf                  3.6.0            py35h0a44026_0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2    defaults
pydot                     1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py35h655552a_2    defaults
python                    3.5.0                         1    defaults
python-dateutil           2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
python-graphviz           0.14.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2021.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    3.12             py35hf8cec8a_1    defaults
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py35_0    defaults
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1    defaults
qtconsole                 4.3.1                    py35_0    defaults
readline                  6.2                           2    defaults
scikit-image              0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.22.2.post1             pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0            py35hcaad992_0    defaults
setuptools                36.4.0                   py35_1    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_2    defaults
sip                       4.19.8           py35h0a44026_0    defaults
six                       1.15.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               hffcf06c_0    defaults
tensorflow                1.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.6                      py35_0    defaults
theano                    1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.5.18                        0    defaults
tornado                   4.5.3                    py35_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0    defaults
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0    defaults
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
xz                        5.0.5                         1    defaults
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3    defaults
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using TF 1.0 ? Your example works perfectly with TF 2.4.

Comment: @Lescurel Cause I'm going to use the vis.visualization.visualize_saliency function to calculate saliency map of my input data, however It can't work(raise some ERROR) if I use higher python/tensorflow/keras version. Is there any solution? Thanks for your comment. ^.^

Comment: If you would go with TF1.0, you might have to avoid Keras layers. use tf.placeholder(...), and tf.nn.conv2d.